# Jquery Mobile Panel not working after update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

The following code was working fine in previous jquery mobile versions. After update the panel does not open after switching pages more than twice.  I have two pages, both pages have same panel.Have not used any Javascript for panel.Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
      <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
      <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
      <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> 
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
        <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a>

        </div> 

      <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
      <a href="#myPanel" >!</a>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p>Welcome! Page 1</p>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
      <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 


    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> 
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
        <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a>

        </div> 

      <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#myPanel" >!</a>
      <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p>Welcome! Page 2</p>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
      <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You cannot use identical IDs in html, thats probably causing your problems.

Comment: But the same code works in previous Jquery Mobile versions.

Comment: While it might work for some reason on some vesions, you still shouldn't because its bad practice and clearly can cause errors.

Comment: Yes Having identical IDs causes problem in new version. I have updated the code with two panels, and touch event support. https://jsfiddle.net/dineshdev/0trtfu5x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though it is definitely caused because you have duplicate panels. Not sure why it was working before but not after updating the jquery mobile library though, but it makes sense that an update would address this obvious problem.

[You'll find documentation here in regards to external panels](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/)

It says you can place the panel outside of the page, but you'll have to initialise it manually, like so:

```
    $(function () {
        $("[data-role='panel']").panel();
    });
```

Working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/4jmewbo5/

Also, your <ul> panel list was missing a closing tag </ul>